# No funciona la autenticación de jwt en srping boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

No logro hacer que funcione la autenticación de JWT en Spring boot y Java 17. Tengo un modelo de capas donde hay una capa model, una repository, una service y la capa controller.
Si quito toda la lógica de autenticación de la clase UsersController los metodos funcionan, puedo crear usuarios, llamarlos mediante get y eliminarlos. Pero no me funcionan si dejo la autenticacion e intento loguearme y creo es por el método "obtenerUsuarioPorCredenciales", por algún motivo este no esta funcionando y no logro ver el porque. La consola de Spring boot no devuelve ningún error. Ademas del JWT uso otro método de encriptación que es el Argon2, puedo que esto no sea necesario, quizá este ahí el error. Alguna sugerencia.
Postman me devuelve este error cuando intento loguearme:

```
"org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [FROM users WHERE email = :email]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [FROM users WHERE email = :email]",
```

Esta es mi clase modelo:

```
package aplicacionWeb.Web.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode
public class Users  {
    
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "email")
   private String email;

   @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "password")
   private String password;
}
```

Esta es mi clase controller del usuario:

```
import aplicacionWeb.Web.service.IUsersService;
import aplicacionWeb.Web.model.Users;
import aplicacionWeb.Web.service.UsersService;
import aplicacionWeb.Web.utils.JWTUtil;
import de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2;
import de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UsersController {
  
   @Autowired
   private IUsersService usuarioDao;  // private UsuarioDao usuarioDao

   @Autowired
   private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

   @RequestMapping(value = "ver/usuarios", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public List<Users> getUsuarios(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token) {
       if (!validarToken(token)) { return null; }
       return usuarioDao.getUsuarios();
   }

   private boolean validarToken(String token) {
       String usuarioId = jwtUtil.getKey(token);
       return usuarioId != null;
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "crear/usuarios", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public void registrarUsuario(@RequestBody Users usuario) {
       Argon2 argon2 = Argon2Factory.create(Argon2Factory.Argon2Types.ARGON2id);
       String hash = argon2.hash(1, 1024, 1, usuario.getPassword());
       usuario.setPassword(hash); 
       usuarioDao.registrar(usuario);
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "api/usuarios/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
   public void eliminar(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token,
                         @PathVariable Long id) {
      if (!validarToken(token)) { return; } 
      usuarioDao.eliminar(id);
   }
}
```

Esta es mi clase authController desade donde realizo la autenticacion:

```
import aplicacionWeb.Web.service.IUsersService;
import aplicacionWeb.Web.model.Users;
import aplicacionWeb.Web.service.UsersService;
import aplicacionWeb.Web.utils.JWTUtil;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    private IUsersService usuarioDao;  // private UsuarioDao usuarioDao
    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;
    @RequestMapping(value = "api/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestBody Users usuario) {
        Users usuarioLogueado = usuarioDao.obtenerUsuarioPorCredenciales (usuario);
        if (usuarioLogueado != null) {
            String tokenJwt = jwtUtil.create(String.valueOf(usuarioLogueado.getId()), usuarioLogueado.getEmail());
            return tokenJwt;
        }
        return "FAIL";
    }
}
```

Esta es la capa repository:

```
package aplicacionWeb.Web.repository;
import aplicacionWeb.Web.model.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository <Users, Long>{    
}
```

Esta es la capa service:

```
import aplicacionWeb.Web.model.Users;
import aplicacionWeb.Web.repository.UsersRepository;
import de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2;
import de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UsersService implements IUsersService {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;    
    @Autowired
    public UsersRepository usersRepo;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    
       public List<Users> getUsuarios() {
       return usersRepo.findAll();
    }
    

    @Override
    public void eliminar(Long id) {
        Users usuario = entityManager.find(Users.class, id);
        entityManager.remove(usuario);
    } 
 
    @Override
    public void registrar(Users usuario) {
        entityManager.merge(usuario);
    } 
    
@Transactional  
  @Override
    public Users obtenerUsuarioPorCredenciales(Users usuario) {
        String query = "FROM users WHERE email = :email" ;      
        List<Users> lista = entityManager.createQuery(query)
                .setParameter("email", usuario.getEmail())
                .getResultList();

        if (lista.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        String passwordHashed = lista.get(0).getPassword();
        Argon2 argon2 = Argon2Factory.create(Argon2Factory.Argon2Types.ARGON2id);
        if (argon2.verify(passwordHashed, usuario.getPassword())) {
            return lista.get(0);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Esta es la interface con los métodos del servicio:

```
import aplicacionWeb.Web.model.Users;
import java.util.List;

public interface IUsersService {
  public  List<Users> getUsuarios();
   public void eliminar(Long id);
   public void registrar(Users usuario);
   public Users obtenerUsuarioPorCredenciales(Users usuario);  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin un stacktrace con mas información y sin conocer la app en detalle es dificil asegurar que pueda estar pasando. Basandome solo en la información del error que te esta generando mi sospecha es que pueda ser el query JPA como tal que estas usando:

```
String query = "FROM users WHERE email = :email" ;
```

En este caso el nombre de la entidad `users` deberia ser `Users` y mapearlo a un objeto, algo por el estilo:

```
String query = "FROM Users u WHERE u.email = :email";
```

Recuerda que los nombres de entidades, de identificadores y de campos de las entidades son sensibles a mayusculas/minusculas (case sensitive). Un post (viejito) con mas info y ejemplos https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs40/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html y uno mas reciente https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtl.html#bnbtm.

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Ese era el error, tenia que cambiar users por Users. Genial!! Muchas gracias!!